# Is there a yaml editing module for ansible?

Tags: ansible

I need to modify a yaml file ([schleuder configuration](http://schleuder2.nadir.org/documentation/v2.2/index.html)) and I'd like to do this from an ansible playbook - is there a module to do so? Hard to google for this, everything that turns up is how to write playbooks.

Answer (score 44):

I also have the need to config manage yaml files. I have written an ansible module that attempts to be idempotent while editing yaml files.

I call it yedit (yaml-edit).  https://github.com/kwoodson/ansible-role-yedit

Please let me know if you find it useful.  I'll be adding features when our team runs into the need, by request, or by pull-request.

Here is a simple playbook example:

```
roles:
- lib_yaml_editor

tasks:
- name: edit some yaml
  yedit:
    src: /path/to/yaml/file
    key: foo
    value: bar

- name: more complex data structure
  yedit:
    src: /path/to/yaml/file
    key: a#b#c#d
    value:
      e:
        f:  This is a test
```

Should produce something that looks like this:

```
foo: bar
a:
  b:
    c:
      d:
        e:
          f: This is a test
```

Edit: 5/27/2018

Comment: Very nice module... I didn't now you could install a role and directly use it... Literally _blew my mind_.

Comment: Can you add this to Ansible Galaxy?

Comment: I have added it to ansible-galaxy.  Only downside was I had to rename in order for the galaxy import tool to find it.

Comment: Does this work with a yaml having multiple documents ? If yes, can you please point me to  any working example ?

Answer (score 14):

One way to accomplish this is to read the file into a fact, update the facts as needed, and then later write the facts back to a yaml file.

```
- name: Read the yaml
  slurp:
    path: myfile.yaml
  register: r_myfile

- name: extract the data
  set_fact:
    mydata: "{{ r_myfile['content'] | b64decode | from_yaml }}"
```

Then update the facts, for instance with the [ansible.utils.update_fact module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html) as needed.

```
- name: Write back to a file
  copy:
    content: '{{ mydata | to_nice_yaml }}'
    dest: myfile.yaml
```

You need to be aware, of course, that this makes the whole update non-atomic.

**Update:** my original suggestion used lookup( 'file' ) but that of course accesses a local file. slurp is the correct way to read a remote file.

Comment: a little more detail about how to change the contents of the yaml file would really help make this shine.

Comment: @Josiah - good point. I was unable to find a way to change an existing dictionary in Ansible. The only solution I could find was to create a new fact with the same name, and use the `combine` filter to replace keys in the original dict as needed.

Comment: Seems like [the update_fact module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html) is the way to go.

Comment: Nice solution, but this removes the existing comments in the yaml file, any way to retain the comments?

Answer (score 8):

Building on Kevin and Bogd's answers, if you want to merge nested keys rather than overwrite whole branches of your YAML file, you must enable recursion in the combine function:

```
mydata: "{{ mydata | combine(newdata, recursive=True) }}"
```

From the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries):

> recursive
> Is a boolean, default to False. Should the combine recursively merge nested hashes. Note: It does not depend on the value of the hash_behaviour setting in ansible.cfg.

So the full solution becomes:

```
- name: Open yaml file
  slurp:
    path: myfile.yaml
  register: r_myfile

- name: Read yaml to dictionary
  set_fact:
    mydata: "{{ r_myfile['content'] | b64decode | from_yaml }}"

- name: Patch yaml dictionary
  set_fact:
    mydata: "{{ mydata | combine(newdata, recursive=True) }}"
  vars: 
    newdata:
      existing_key:
        existing_nested_key: new_value
        new_nested_key: new_value

- name: Write yaml file
  copy:
    content: '{{ mydata | to_nice_yaml }}'
    dest: myfile.yaml
```

Note: recursion only enables adding nested keys, or replacing nested values. Deleting specific nested keys would require a more advanced solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such module. You can check this by looking at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_all_modules.html

Your best bet is to use either [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) or [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) or [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) modules.

Comment: I recommend blockinfile as well https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html

Answer (score 3):

This is based on Kevin Keane's answer - I just added the fact modification section. And since it seems impossible to edit the existing answer (edit queue is full), I just added this for anyone else who (like me) comes here looking for the details.

1. Read the YAML data from the file, and create a fact storing that data:

   ```
   - name: Read the yaml 
     slurp:
       path: myfile.yaml
     register: r_myfile

   - name: extract the data
     set_fact:
       mydata: "{{ r_myfile['content'] | b64decode | from_yaml }}"
   ```
2. I was unable to find any way of modifying an existing dictionary in Ansible in place. So the workaround for actually modifying the data is to create a new dict, with the same name as the existing fact (`mydata`), and use the `combine` filter to change keys as needed:

   ```
   - name: Create configuration for core - modify params
     set_fact:
       mydata: "{{ mydata | combine(newdata) }}"
     vars: 
       newdata:
         old_key: new_value
         new_key: new_value
   ```
3. Write the modified data to the file:

   ```
   - name: Write back to a file
     copy:
       content: '{{ mydata | to_nice_yaml }}'
       dest: myfile.yaml
   ```

Results:

Original myfile.yaml:

```
 ---
 another_key: another_value  # This is a key that we will not touch
 old_key: old_value          # This is an old key, that we will change
```

File after playbook execution:

```
 another_key: another_value
 new_key: new_value
 old_key: new_value
```

Note that (as you probably expected) all comments are gone, since you are just reading the YAML data, and writing that back.

Answer (score 1):

While there are enough answers that cover the modification of YAML files, I want to add how you can remove entire keys from a YAML file, as this can be a challenge:

- [How to remove a single key from an Ansible dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40496021/11942268)
- [Removing a deeply-nested dict item in Ansible](https://medium.com/@jmazzite/removing-a-deeply-nested-dict-item-in-ansible-c8958e9be57f)
- [Removing a deeply-nested dict item in Ansible - Another solution](https://medium.com/@zoredache/another-solution-3cf120492f35)

Unfortunately, there is still no official module like there is for INI files ([community.general.ini_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html)). In order to modify YAML files, it is still (at least) a good practice to read the file, modify the content and write it back to the file:

```yaml
- name: Read yaml
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /path/to/file.yml
  register: slurped_yaml

- name: Modify yaml
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    modified_yaml: |
      {% set my_dict = slurped_yaml.content | b64decode | from_yaml %}
      {% set a = my_dict.path.to.my.pop('key') %}
      {{ my_dict }}

- name: Write yaml
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    content: '{{ modified_yaml | to_nice_yaml }}'
    dest: /path/to/file.yml
```

For a YAML file like:

```yaml
path:
  to:
    my:
      key: remove me
```

These tasks would remove `key: remove me` from it.