# How to remove a single key from an Ansible dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I'd like to remove a single key from a dictionary in Ansible.

For example, I'd like this:

```
- debug: var=dict2
  vars:
    dict:
      a: 1
      b: 2
      c: 3
    dict2: "{{ dict | filter_to_remove_key('a') }}"
```

To print this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict2": {
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}
```

Please note that the dictionary is loaded from a json file and I POST it to the Grafana REST API. I'd like to allow saving an 'id' key in the file and remove the key before POSTing it.

This is closer to the actual use I have for the removal:

```
- name: Install Dashboards   
  uri:
    url: "{{ grafana_api_url }}/dashboards/db"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: Bearer {{ grafana_api_token }}
    body:
      overwrite: true
      dashboard:
        "{{ lookup('file', item) | from_json | removekey('id') }}"
    body_format: json   with_fileglob:
    - "dashboards/*.json"
    - "../../../dashboards/*.json"
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new dictionary ? Why are not you using the original dictionary  and skipping the desired key while printing ?

Comment: I guess you can only set key to null with default filters: `dict | combine({'a':None})`, if it suits your needs. Otherwise you need to write your custom filter plugin.

Comment: @Shasha99 the second dictionary is just to help show the kind of thing I need. I don't actually need to print the dictionary; I need to POST it to grafana. So I need a key to be gone. I'll try to clarify a little better in my question.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks for the suggestion, though it does leave a key with the value 'null'. I'll post a solution using a filter, unless you'd like to.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov ...and I just noticed that you realized that your suggestion would leave a 'null' value :)

Comment: @DavidResnick Well in that case, the simplest would be to create a new ansible module using python and use it according to your need. let me know if you need further help for the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
- set_fact:
    dict:
      a: 1
      b: 2
      c: 3
    dict2: {}

- set_fact:
    dict2: "{{dict2 |combine({item.key: item.value})}}"
  when: "{{item.key not in ['a']}}"
  with_dict: "{{dict}}"

- debug: var=dict2
```

or create a filter plugin and use it.

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. I created a filter plugin, but it's cleaner to make do with native ansible if possible.

Comment: Very nice! You don't even have to declare dict2, you can use {} directly.

Comment: What about deeper nested keys?

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish this by using
[combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) and [omit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional)

```
- set_fact:
    dict:
      a: 1
      b: 2
      c: 3

- debug:
    var: dict

- debug:
    msg: "{{ dict | combine({ 'a': omit }) }}"
```

```
TASK [test : set_fact] 
ok: [server]

TASK [test: debug] 
ok: [server] => {
    "dict": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}

TASK [test : debug] 
ok: [server] => {
    "msg": {
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: `omit` is Ansible related thing, should be used carefully:
`ansible -i localhost, --connection local all -m shell -a 'echo {{ {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3} | combine({"b":omit}) }}'`

localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
{a: 1, c: 3, b: __omit_place_holder__233cf870e2b7d8a20717f23637c641c4fd1077aa}

- it is not omitted.

Answer (score 6):

```
  - debug: var=dict2
    vars:
      dict:
        a: 1
        b: 2
        c: 3
      dict2: '{{ dict | dict2items | rejectattr("key", "eq", "a") | list | items2dict }}'
      #dict2: '{{ dict | dict2items | rejectattr("key", "match", "^(a|b)$") | list | items2dict }}'
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict2": {
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! It is possible to shorten this `... | list | items2dict` to this `... | items2dict` (omit unnecessary `| list`)

Comment: Without `list` you will get an error: `items2dict requires a list, got <type 'generator'> instead`

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach inspired by an [article by John Mazzitelli](https://medium.com/@jmazzite/removing-a-deeply-nested-dict-item-in-ansible-c8958e9be57f) that can be used inline without additional `set_fact` tasks, etc.:

#### Task:

```yaml
tasks:
- debug: var=dict2
  vars:
    dict:
      a: 1
      b: 2
      c: 3
    # It is important that there be NO WHITESPACE outside of `{% ... %}` and `{{ ... }}`
    # or else the var will be converted to a string.  The copy() step optionally prevents
    # modifying the original. If you don't care, then: "{% set removed=dict.pop('a') %}{{dict}}"
    dict2: "{% set copy=dict.copy() %}{% set removed=copy.pop('a') %}{{ copy }}"
```

#### Outputs:

```
TASK [debug] ***********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict2": {
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ansible.utils.remove_keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/remove_keys_filter.html) filter. It will remove the given key(s) on *all* nesting layers. So it might not be suitable in every scenario:

```yaml
- debug: var=dict2
  vars:
    dict:
      a: 1
      b: 2
      c: 3
    dict2: "{{ dict | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['a']) }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  dict2:
    b: 2
    c: 3
```

---

If you want to remove a particular key on a particular layer, you can pop that key away like this:

```yaml
- debug: var=dict2
  vars:
    dict:
      a: 1
      b: 2
      c: 3
    dict2: |
      {% set a = dict.pop('a') %}
      {{ dict }}
```

Example with deeper nesting:

```yaml
- debug: var=dict2
  vars:
    dict:
      sub_dict:
        a: 1
        b: 2
        c: 3
    dict2: |
      {% set a = dict.sub_dict.pop('a') %}
      {{ dict }}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you interested in filter (which is in my opinion the cleanest way to delete an item in dict) then create `filter_plugins/dicts.py` in directory, which your playbook resides in, and fill it with:

```
'''Custom ansible filters for dicts'''

import copy


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'del_by_list': self.del_by_list
        }

    def del_by_list(self, dict_to_reduce, list_of_keys):
        '''Deletes items of dict by list of keys provided'''
        dict_to_return = copy.deepcopy(dict_to_reduce)
        for item in list_of_keys:
            if item in dict_to_return:
                del dict_to_return[item]
        return dict_to_return
```

And you good to go:

```
---
- hosts: hadoop
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ {123: 456, 789: 123} | del_by_list([123]) }}"
```

This will yield `{789: 123}`