# Ansible - Remove key-value Pair

Tags: ansible

I have a list of dictionaries

```yaml
member:
  - name: test2
    orig: test2
  - name: test1
    orig: test1
```

and would like to remove the *orig* key and value from all dictionaries in the list.

```yaml
- name: Print Firewall Group Member
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ member }}"
```

```
TASK [Print Firewall Group Member] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [fortigate01] => (item={'name': 'test2', 'orig': 'test2'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "test2",
        "orig": "test2"
    }
}
ok: [fortigate01] => (item={'name': 'test1', 'orig': 'test1'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "test1",
        "orig": "test1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a single key from an Ansible dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496021/how-to-remove-a-single-key-from-an-ansible-dictionary)

Comment: Hi Roberto, it seems the question has already been answered multiple times on this site, please check if any of these are applicable to you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ansible+remove+dictionary+key

Comment: @Kristian although it has been answered, none of the solutions is as good as the one posted by Vladimir below. Hence I suggest to **not** close this one. I'll personally use it as a reference.

Comment: @Zeitounator I agree, this solution is better that the other ones. On the other hand, having duplicate questions with different answers is confusing so I feel that the original should be updated instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the filter [*ansible.utils.remove_keys*](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/blob/main/docs/ansible.utils.remove_keys_filter.rst). For example, given simplified data

```yaml
member:
  - name: test2
    orig: test2
  - name: test1
    orig: test1
```

Declare the variable

```yaml
names: "{{ member|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['orig']) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
names:
  - name: test2
  - name: test1
```

2. Optionally, use the filter [*ansible.utils.keep_keys*](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/blob/main/docs/ansible.utils.keep_keys_filter.rst). The declaration below gives the same result

```yaml
names: "{{ member|ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=['name']) }}"
```

3. The next option is *json_query*

```yaml
names: "{{ member|json_query('[].{name: name}') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    member:
      - name: test2
        orig: test2
      - name: test1
        orig: test1

    names: "{{ member|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['orig']) }}"
    name2: "{{ member|ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=['name']) }}"
    name3: "{{ member|json_query('[].{name: name}') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: names
    - debug:
        var: name2
    - debug:
        var: name3
```

Comment: Beware that this is a relatively new functionality and you might need to either install `ansible.utils` via ansible-galaxy or use pip to install ansible (>=5.4.0). For example latest Ubuntu LTS (22.04) ansible package does not contain this functionality.

Comment: You should check your repos. [Ansible 6.6](https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible?field.series_filter=jammy) is available in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish atm. In addition to this, there are [community builds](https://pypi.org/project/ansible/) available.

Comment: Oh, adding ansible ppa does bring the updates indeed - my bad. I only tested this with the stock ubuntu repos.

Comment: Note that on the [latest official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html) the only documented installation method for ansible is through pip: