# How to use Ansible Jinja2 reject filter?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to reject/exclude `xyz`'s keys from an `info` list

```json
    "info": [
        {
            "effect": {
                "com": "both",
                "policy": {
                    "name": "auto"
                },
                "schedule": "-",
                "state": "enabled"
            },
            "name": "test_inline",
            "abc": {
                "name": "svm1",
                "xyz": "56a0599f"
            },
            "xyz": "42d6-56a0599f"
        }
    ]
```

via

```yaml
- set_fact:
    info : "{{ info | default ([]) + facts | json_query('response.records') | reject('equalto','xyz') }}"
```

and I've tried also

```yaml
reject('match', '[xyz]')
```

But still `xyz` keys are not excluded from the `info` list.

Comment: Your `reject` filter is applying to the result of `json_query('response.records')`, but that doesn't appear to match anything in your `info` variable (there is neither `response` key or a `records` key).

Comment: oh..then is there other way to exclude?

Comment: "_is there other way to exclude?_", sure, see in example [How to remove a single key from an Ansible dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496021/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you try to achieve, a  [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    info: [
        {
            "effect": {
                "com": "both",
                "policy": {
                    "name": "auto"
                },
                "schedule": "-",
                "state": "enabled"
            },
            "name": "test_inline",
            "abc": {
                "name": "svm1",
                "xyz": "56abcdef"
            },
            "xyz": "1234-56abcdef"
        }
    ]

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ info | first | dict2items | rejectattr('key', 'eq', 'xyz') | list | items2dict }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ info | combine({'xyz': omit}) }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    abc:
      name: svm1
      xyz: 56abcdef
    effect:
      com: both
      policy:
        name: auto
      schedule: '-'
      state: enabled
    name: test_inline
```

For all occurrences of key `xyz` you may need to adopt the [`remove_keys` filter – Remove specific keys from a data recursively](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/remove_keys_filter.html). It works on dict and list.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ info | first | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target='xyz') }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ info | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target='xyz') }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - abc:
      name: svm1
    effect:
      com: both
      policy:
        name: auto
      schedule: '-'
      state: enabled
    name: test_inline
```

**Credits To**

- [How to remove a single key from an Ansible dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496021/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter [ansible.utils.remove_keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/remove_keys_filter.html). For example,

```yaml
  result: "{{ info|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['xyz']) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    - abc: {name: svm1}
      effect:
        com: both
        policy: {name: auto}
        schedule: '-'
        state: enabled
      name: test_inline
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    info:
      - abc: {name: svm1, xyz: 56abcdef}
        effect:
          com: both
          policy: {name: auto}
          schedule: '-'
          state: enabled
        name: test_inline
        xyz: 1234-56abcdef

    result: "{{ info|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['xyz']) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
```